# Having action take place onclick of parent, but not specific children

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a scenario, where clicking on the parent container should open a hidden div. But when clicking on anchors or buttons, that are in the same parent container - their natural action should take place, and not the open/close of the inner div.

HTML:

```
<div id="row1" class="ticketRow alert">
  <div class="btn-group actionButtons">
    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-default">Menu <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="javascript:;" data-action="close">Task 1</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" data-action="pending">Task 2</a></li>


    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="ticketMeta">Ticket Meta</div>

  <a class="btn" href="javascript:alert('hello');">text link</a>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".ticketRow").on("click", function() {
  $(this).find(".ticketMeta").slideToggle();
});
$(".ticketRow .btn").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

So what happens is that the code, is that is works find for the `<a>` anchor, but not the drop down/button. ie, when you click on the button - nothing happens (everything is blocked), when what should happen, is that ONLY the menu should open.
As it is, this jquery above seems to be written in an un-economical way, seen as it parses both piece of code on each click (I assume, right?)

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/24de8rLz/2/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply modify you event handler for parent container event listener like this below.

```
if(event.currentTarget.id == event.target.id){
  $(this).find(".ticketMeta").slideToggle();
}
```

This should solve your problem.

And remove

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I meant and hoping this would solve your problem